# Can't pass a text area value to my form

Tags: javascript, php, html, mysql, forms

I'm currently re-designing a page on my site that allows registered users to send messages to the administrators. All the code I'm using is already fully functional on the other page but after moving everything across, it has stopped working, which has baffled me.

```
<textarea name="content" id="msgs" class="convo" ></textarea>
```

The text area is as simple as it gets, the form is wrapped around TR tags.
I know the form is working because I also submit to the form the date/time and the email address' of the sender and receiver. The form executes 'compose.php', writes to the database successfully and re-directs back to the customer's profile. The problem is that the "new" message is blank. Everything was sent to the form apart from the contents of the text area.

If I use a plain text area then everything works, so the problem has to be the 'WYSIWYG Content Editor' that I apply to the text area, even though it works fine on the other page?

```
bkLib.onDomLoaded
(
  function()
  { 
    new nicEditor({buttonList : ['bold','italic','underline','left','center','right','ol','ul','fontFamily','fontSize','fore    color','link','unlink']}).panelInstance('msgs');
  }
);
```

**Does anyone have any idea where I can start? I've been troubleshooting this for a good few hours and it's starting to get the best of me! If you need any other snippets of code, let me know.**

EDIT

Maybe this will help...

```
<textarea name="content" id="msgs" class="convo" >TEST MESSAGE</textarea>
```

When the page loads, "TEST MESSAGE" is written to the text area. If I submit it, the value is passed to the form and then to the database etc... But if I remove it and type my own words, nothing is sent across?

Comment: (Thanks @Wireblue !) What is the error you are getting?  I'm not sure the problem is with the content editor.

Comment: Are you able to use the developer tools in your browser to confirm the textarea field is being POSTed to the processing page/script? Perhaps write some code on the processing page to echo/dump all the POST variables and confirm the textarea one is present?

Comment: The text area does not post it's content to the form if the content editor is active, however a basic text area will.

Comment: I'll take somewhat of an educated guess `.panelInstance('msgs')` since `.panelInstance` may be a "class" (*as they are in jQuery with a dot and CSS*), and you're using `id="msgs"` and `class="convo"` shouldn't that be `.panelInstance('convo')`?

Comment: If that was the case, the content editor would not initialize.

Comment: Does your PHP contain anything to the effect of `$content=$_POST['content'];`? That's the usual PHP forms naming convention. @CraigyCraigo

Comment: Yes it does. All of the code is taken from a previous webpage that is fully functional, both forms call the same script and both use a content editor. I have no idea what makes this new page so different...

Comment: I noticed `'fore    color'` has whitespace in the middle of it. Have you tried removing it?

Comment: The gap does not exist on my script, must have appeared when I pasted it here.

Comment: does the new page use an SSL cert?  I had a similar problem when converting a site to use SSL.  random stuff stops working.  I'm pretty sure that you'll lose $_POST going from `http://` to `https://`

Comment: Hm... I kind of doubt it but not impossible. I have seen cases before where a hidden uuencoded character played tricks on me a few times. The characters would only show up in my IDE.

Comment: Ahh, no worries. ;) Have you tried temporarily removing the config? Have you tried upgrading to the latest version of the Editor? Can you use the dev tools in your browser to check that the editor has created a hidden textarea behind the scenes?

Comment: @Nazca No SSL cert on either page.

Comment: Everyone please check my edited question above.

Comment: Make sure that all the dependencies your text editor needs are still included in the page.  For trouble shooting you might go to the old version and just include ALL of them in an obvious spot in your new code.  Don't worry if they get included twice for a minute and check to see if it works.

Comment: [http://nicedit.com/docs.php](http://nicedit.com/docs.php) nicedit is no longer under active development.  You might try the authors suggestions.

Comment: Do you suggest I try a different content editor? Everything works fine on the older page so I wouldn't have much hope...

Comment: Truthfully, if the message is going to the admin; why are you allowing formatting any way?  I could see that being a nice feature in a forum, blog, or message board of some sort, but when I code similar scripts, I tend to restrict that kinda stuff as much as possible for fear of XSS.  and... who cares if my admin get to see pretty stuff or not.  http://www.ckeditor.com looks well maintained and is open sourced on github.  You'll probly get farther with them.

Comment: The messages form a discussion/conversation between a customer and a specialist. The messages are usually very big, so its nice that they can be formatted with line breaks, html links and bold/underline etc...

Comment: `so the problem has to be the 'WYSIWYG Content Editor'` and that's the answer

Comment: @EL Thanks but you're incorrect.

Answer (score 0):

**I have managed to fix the problem!**

**The old code was:**

```
<form name="send" id="sndmsg" method="post" action="compose.php">
<tr>
  <td width="90%" class="tab">&nbsp;Compose New Message</td>
</tr>
<tr>
  <td>
    <textarea name="content" id="msgs" class="convo" ></textarea>
  </td>
</tr>
<tr>
  <td>
    <input name="user_s" type="hidden" id="user_s" value="<?PHP echo $user;?>" />
    <input name="user_r" type="hidden" id="user_r" value="<?PHP echo $email;?>" />
    <input name="fname" type="hidden" value="<?PHP echo $fullname;?>" />
    <input type="image" src="/send.png" />
  </td>
</tr>
</form>
```

**Which was clearly, not working. The new code does work, which is the following:**

```
<tr>
  <td width="90%" class="tab">&nbsp;Compose New Message</td>
    <form name="send" id="sndmsg" method="post" action="compose.php">
    <textarea name="content" id="msgs" class="convo" ></textarea>
    <input name="user_s" type="hidden" id="user_s" value="<?PHP echo $user;?>" />
    <input name="user_r" type="hidden" id="user_r" value="<?PHP echo $email;?>" />
    <input name="fname" type="hidden" value="<?PHP echo $fullname;?>" />
    <input type="image" src="/send.png" />
    </form>
  </td>
</tr>
```

Comment: Strange behavior.  Did you happen to try the 'old code' on a different browser than your default?

Comment: @Nazca Nope, Google Chrome on both instances.

Comment: I'm glad you got it working.  But I'm still confused as  to why it woulden't work.  I downloaded nicedit from [http://nicedit.com/download.php](http://nicedit.com/download.php) (the uncompressed version) and the `old code` seems to be working as intended for me using Chrome Version 32.0.1700.76 m